# Best practices to run Angular application inside angularJS application

Tags: angularjs, angular

we have a big AngularJS application which we started to write 3 years ago and still adding new features. I want that the new features will be written in new Angular. converting the while code is impossible as there are many controllers and directives - before there was the concept of components. I am trying to find what are the best practices. to host the new pages inside iframe?

thanks

Comment: Your are probably looking for a way to build an hybrid app which run both AngularJs and Angular : https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a Single Page Application or SPA with a long page life cycle and you are using Angular to handle all your routing then a big concern would be memory leaks.

The concern is the same concern when you have any 2 libraries (Angular vs Angular JS, or Angular vs jQuery, etc.).  You don't want to pass variables between them.  If you can keep the parts of the page where you are using the 2 libraries completely separated from each other and only pass things between the 2 libraries *using the DOM* then you should avoid any memory leaks from circular object references.

Try to avoid creating variables in a global JS scope to pass data between the 2 libraries.  You can set values in the HTML DOM with one library and then retrieve those values from the DOM using another library and you should avoid memory leaks.

But again, this only matters if you are relying on the Angular routing and not doing any complete page links with stuff like `<a href="/someUrl">`.